# Where are the Eclipse key binding icons documented / defined?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I'm returning to using Eclipse after many years with different IDEs.  Moreover, my fingers are most at home with Emacs.  While I've set the key binding scheme in Eclipse to Emacs, I'd like to modify a few things further.

While looking at some of the commands and their current key bindings, I see key "icons" that I don't seem to know how to create and I'm wondering if there is a canonical documenation for the iconology used in Eclipse key bindings.

If nobody can point me at such documentation, then perhaps you could tell me what these keys are supposed to be?  Specifically the two arrows which point down-and-to-the-right and up-and-to-the-left:

[image]

Comment: Are your referring to keep board shortcuts, like as a an example, to block comment a couple lines you select the lines the hold Ctrl-Shift-/ - ditto a shortcut like select text and press a key to indent left or right?  If so I've seen it here before and can look for it for you.  Or am I way off track here and you're looking at altering the key bindings?

Comment: Those are actual keys on the full width Mac keyboard. They aren't on the narrower Mac keyboards.

Comment: @JGlass - while not relevant to the question I asked, what I'm trying to do is make eclipse behave like emacs with respect to mark and cursor move from the perspective of selection.  That is, set-mark, move-cursor, operation (e.g. cut/copy/indent).

Comment: @greg-449 Really?  I've been a mac user for years and I cannot recall ever having a 9x9 set of arrow keys.

Comment: Yes, really. Just these top left / bottom right keys. They are on the keyboard I am typing on. They normally go to the top / bottom of a document .

Comment: Oh, understood - sorry ignore my comment and good luck.  You might post in the eclipse forums. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of my own question, the [image] and [image] icons refer to the `Home` and `End` keys respectively on most keyboards.  Thanks to @greg-449 for the hint.

I'm still on the lookout for a complete list of `key <--> icon` mappings.